# En Quasar cuando trato de ejecutar el método charAt() de JavaScript me devuelve "TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Estoy utilizando el ***framework*** de Vue, [Quasar].

Este es el error que muestra en consola:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined"

Este es mi código:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex q-pa-md">
    <q-list class="full-width" separator="">
      <q-item
        v-for="(user, key) in users"
        :key="key"
        to="/notes"
        clickable
        v-ripple
      >
        <q-item-section avatar>
          <q-avatar color="teal" text-color="white">
            {{ user.name.charAt(0) }}
          </q-avatar>
        </q-item-section>      
      </q-item>
    </q-list>
  </q-page>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  /* data() {
    return {
      users: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Robert",
          online: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Sofia",
          online: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }, */
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("store", ["users"])
  }
};
</script>
```

He probado enviando los valores desde un objeto [data] y me ha funcionado correctamente, sin embargo el valor viene desde un [store], en una propiedad [computed()], cuando lo envío desde ahí es cuando la página se pone en blanco y muestra el error inicial.

Comment: Lo has probado entre [0] en vez de poner entre ()

Comment: Sí, aún así no funciona, también he probado otros métodos para capturar la primer letra pero tampoco me han funcionado. Igual gracias por la sugerencia!

Comment: El error es que claramente `user` no tiene una propiedad llamada `name`. Como obtienes el user? puedes imprimir el user por consola antes?

Comment: Si le quito charAt(0) me trae el nombre del usuario sin problema, pero necesito simplemente mostrar la primer letra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema en realidad no se relaciona con `Quasar` sino con `Vue` o incluso `Javascript`, un error común es escribir **chartAt** con **"t"** (que significaría *gráfico*), en vez de `charAt` (que sería *carácter*).

En el siguiente ejemplo se muestra cómo debería funcionar normalmente

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      name: 'Test'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Nombre de usuario: {{ user.name }} <br>
  Primera letra: {{ user.name.charAt(0) }}
</div>
```

Debes evaluar el valor que te está llegando y también cómo lo estás escribiendo.

Algo que se me ocurre es que la variable `user` no está disponible cuando empieza a ejecutarse el código, si es posible pon la variable dentro del elemento `data` o en la propiedad `computed()` en caso de que el valor venga desde un `store`.

Como última recomendación, valida que todos los elementos de tu objeto existan y que no haya un `undefined`.

Comment: He probado enviando los valores desde un objeto [data] y me ha funcionado correctamente, sin embargo el valor viene desde un [store], por lo que efectivamente está en una propiedad [computed()]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de tu JS?

Comment: Sí el efectivamente el problema era que habían datos que llegaban en undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Dependiendo del contenido de los datos y su origen , en determinados puntos del ciclo de vida del componente puedes operar sobre un valor indefinido o inválido.

En tu caso específico intentas obtener la inicial de un user

```
{{ user.name.charAt(0) }}
```

Lo cual presupone que la variable user  (en este caso es el ítem de un array, pero esto es anecdótico porque un array vacío no entra en el bucle),

- existe
- es un objeto
- tiene una propiedad name
- la propiedad name es un string

En tu ejemplo con `data`

```
 data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: "Robert"} ,  // ✓ cumple
        null, // no existe
        'juanito' // existe pero no es un objeto
        { id: 2 } // es un objeto pero no tiene propiedad name
        { id:3, name: []} // tiene name, pero éste no es un string 
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Como tu componente obtiene los datos del store

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("store", ["users"])
  }
```

habría que ver cómo está inicializado. Por ejemplo:

```
const state = {
 users:[
   {id:null, name:null}
 ]
};
```

Explicaría que el array no esté vacío y sin embargo contenga un user inválido.

Una opción es poner un IF o varios en el template:

```
 <q-item-section avatar v-if="user && user.name && typeof user.name === 'string'">
    ...
 </q-item-section>
```

Otra opción es usar una propiedad calculada para filtrar la data o marshallizarla a esa estructura.

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters("store", ["users"]),
  validUsers() {
     return (this.users || []).filter(user=>{
        return  typeof user === 'object');
     }).map(user=>{
        user.name = user.name || '';
       return user;
     })
   }
}
```

Pero eso es frágil, conlleva un acoplamiento innecesario y es confuso de mantener, para empezar si `user` es `null` ya pasa el filtro (misterios de JS). En rigor la comprobación debiera ser `user.constructor === Object` pero de nuevo, ese objeto puede venir de haber instanciado una clase `User`....  si el componente no sabe ni controla el origen de `users` es buscarse problemas.

Creo que es más práctico y fácil de mantener una coalescencia explicita en el template:

```
String(
   (
     user || {}  // coalescencia a objeto vacio
   ).name || '' // coalescencia a string vacio
).charAt(0) // esto siempre funciona
```

o sea

```
 <q-avatar color="teal" text-color="white">
        {{ String((user||{}).name||'').charAt(0) }}
 </q-avatar>
```

Con eso el componente sólo sabe lo mínimo de los datos, le da igual de donde vengan ni otros detalles de su estructura.

Answer (score 2):

El `string` que mandas a la vista por medio de VueJS no deja de ser un elemento iterable; entonces debería bastar con indicar la posición a la cual deseas acceder de este modo:

```
{{ user.nombre[0] }}
```

De una estructura como la siguiente

```
        let app = new Vue({
          el: `#data`,
          data: {
            nombre: "algoMas"
          }
        })
```

Ahora si tus datos están dentro de un objeto dentro del principal que sería `data` de esta forma:

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: `#data`,
  data: {
    user: {
      nombre: "algo Mas"
    }
  }
})
```

Puedes accederlo de esta forma:

```
{{ user.nombre[0] }}
```

Con lo cual tendrás la letra **a** al indicar que del objeto iterable obtengas el elemento que esta en la posición 0 tal cual *como si fuera un vector*

Comment: He probado enviando los valores desde un objeto [data] y me ha funcionado correctamente, sin embargo el valor viene desde un [store], en una propiedad [computed()], cuando lo envío desde ahí es cuando la página se pone en blanco y muestra el error inicial.

Comment: Convendría entonces agregues para ampliar y clarificar tu duda